# How to make Shape like this?

Tags: android, xml, shapes

I want to get shape similar to what you can see below. The thing I am missing is the header color (the color behind Anonymous text). I've reproduced what I wanted by simply moving mouse over second textview which is now highlighted and makes this effect :)

Current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">
 <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000" />
 <gradient android:startColor="#898989" android:endColor="#B5B5B5" android:angle="270"/> 

 <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
 android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [Layer List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) that contains two drawables.

For example, the first will cover the whole shape, and the second will overlay it but with `android:top="10dp"` set, to create an offset showing the underlying first shape

**Edit:**
Like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#000000" />

            <solid android:color="#00ff00" />

            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="#B5B5B5"
                android:startColor="#898989" />

            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems even a better solution.

Comment: ... but it's not perfectly OK - now I have stroke around whole title too! Is it possible to set stroke only to left, top and right border?

Comment: No problem, I made an edit.
(Remove the stroke from the second shape and add item offsets in the size of the stroke)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LinearLayout` and place two `TextView` with different shapes as background.

The first one having its upper corners rounded and the second one its bottom corners.

Answer (score 0):

this tools might be helpful further in development

> http://angrytools.com/
>
> http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html